# How do I include external plain .as file in pure actionscript project (packages/classes)?

Tags: actionscript-3, include, flash-builder

I'm building Action Script project in Flash Builder. No flex, no third party libs. Pure actionscript - hierarchy of packages and classes. How do I include a plain external .as file, which is not a package or class, but just a set of statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe you'll have to package it as a class in order to call its elements.  that doesn't mean you have to include a constructor, though.  you can have a class that simply contains static constants, variables and functions.

Comment: I ended up doing just that. Thanks. I just wonder if it's possible at all.